# User referral points system Angular

Tags: angular, point

I am using Angular, Node.js and Mongo.

I have setup a sign-up form, whereby when a user signs up via a referral link at mysite.com/sign-up/:referrerId, the referring user is stored in the new user document in the 'user' collection. I am using MongoDB, and the 'referringUser' is stored as an ObjectId for the new user who has signed up.

The site has a points system, so that when the user signs up, they are awarded 25 points as a welcome bonus.

I would like to reward the user who made the referral with 50 points, but only when the new user reaches 100 points.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to the best way to achieve this?

An example of a user document below:

```
_id: 63f3e3f806243d96df30f5e6
name: "Username"
email: "test@aolsds.com"
passwordHash: "$2a$10$JIEeeu93Qe.gMgsHEW02m.8nwk498rW5raWRlzF4GoPRONq2Un./O"
referringUser: ObjectId(63b31c01dcf76fa785f89ffd)
points: 25
createdAt: 2023-02-20T21:19:00.000+00:00
```

I'm struggling to conceptually decide how to approach this.